# Width, length and dynamic pricing - Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

We've built quite a few sites in Craft CMS and have been waiting for a project to get stuck into Craft Commerce - that time is here! BUT, one thing - it's for a carpet company so allowing the user to add a width and length of carpet is critical.

After reading many similar questions, I see that everyone's pointing to creating variants for each option. This isn't practical for this case as they have many types of widths let alone being able to type in a length. Plus, they get new stock quite often.

They're currently using WooCommerce and we really don't want to go back to Magento so it'll be a shame if we couldn't use Craft Commerce.

So here are my questions - has anybody released a plugin that can do the above? If not, is a plugin the way to go for this? Finally, are there any plans to add this functionality into Craft Commerce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like this is a job for a Custom Purchasable.

Basically you write a plugin such that your created element meets the Purchasable interface, which handles it's own pricing calculations etc., and that custom purchasable becomes a sellable item through Commerce.

Documentation is here: https://craftcommerce.com/docs/purchasables

Other than that, I can't see why Commerce wouldn't work well for such a scenario as it allows for complete flexibility with front end presentation and checkout.

Comment: Sounds like a plan! I've had a quick read and looks the right direction to go in. Thanks! Commerce does tick all the boxes otherwise and Craft is our CMS of choice so want to stick with it.

Comment: @JonnyT just curious, was this approach successful for you?